# Kotlin Firebase Parsing Duplication

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a Game object that has an init block where I setup the object and upload to the Firebase Firestore. Then when I'm listening for changes in that object I have to convert the DocumentSnapshot to a Game object.

```
game = snapshot.toObject(Game::class.java)
```

Pretty simple. The problem is is that this calls the init block of my Game class and uploads another game object. Is there a way I can avoid calling the init block while doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use automatic field mapping like this, the convention is that you should use a class definition that contains *only* the fields you want to map, and nothing else.  Objects that have only getters and setters for properties are called JavaBeans, and their sole purpose is to store data.  These objects must define a default no-arg constructor.

If you have additional logic that works with your Game object, that should go in a different class. It's better design to keep your data separate from the logic that works with the data (as you have discovered).

Comment: Yes. I just created a GameGenerator class that now deals with all the code. Much cleaner and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your init code to a constructor, which you can call when you're creating an instance of your Game class and you want it to upload the game object.

Comment: Doesn't work. The above code still calls the constructor

Comment: Firebase SDK will call your default no-argument constructor. Define another constructor (i.e. with some arguments), which will not be called.